# Java Canvas Rotating Points Along A Circle

Tags: java, canvas, rotation

I'm trying to make an Asteroids remake using Java and I'm having problems making the player (which is a triangle) rotate when I press a button. I have looked up methods and the math to make the points of the triangle rotate but I haven't figured out how to use the formulas. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import Main.GameObject;
import Main.ID;

public class Player extends GameObject {

    public float x1 = 16 + xPos;
    public float y1 = 0 + yPos;
    public float x2 = 0 + xPos;
    public float y2 = 48 + yPos;
    public float x3 = 32 + xPos;
    public float y3 = 48 + yPos;

    public float centerX = xPos + 16;
    public float centerY = yPos - 24;

    public Point2D.Float center = new Point2D.Float(xPos + 16, yPos - 24);

    public Point2D.Float p1 = new Point2D.Float(x1, y1);
    public Point2D.Float p2 = new Point2D.Float(x2, y2);
    public Point2D.Float p3 = new Point2D.Float(x3, y3);

    public Player(float startX, float startY, ID id) {
        super(startX, startY, id);
        this.xPos = startX;
        this.yPos = startY;
        this.id = id;

    }

    public void tick() {

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(p1, p2));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(p2, p3));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(p3, p1));
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return null;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            //Rotate triangle here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without pertinent code and a more specific question, I don't see how anyone can help you, so I'm going to ask you to improve this question -- a lot.  You can see exactly what we need by checking out the [help] site, especially the links on [how to ask a decent question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The code we need is a [mcve]. Enough to fully understand your problem. All code should be posted here as an edit to your question  and not in a link. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate a single point around the origin (0,0).

```
float rot = 2.0; // angle in radians
Point2D.Float p1 = new Point2D.Float(10.0,10.0);
Point2D.Float p1Rotated = new Point2D.Float(0,0);
float dx = Math.cos(rot);
float dy = Math.sin(rot);
p1Rotated.x = p1.x * dx + p1.y * -dy;
p1Rotated.y = p1.x * dy + p1.y * dx;
```

So for a triangle that has its center at 0,0 do the above to each point then position the triangle by adding the offset to each point.

```
float rot = 2.0; // angle in radians
float x = 100.0; // space ship center at 100,100
float y = 100.0; 
Point2D.Float p1 = new Point2D.Float(10.0,10.0);
Point2D.Float p2 = new Point2D.Float(-10.0,10.0);
Point2D.Float p3 = new Point2D.Float(0.0,-10.0);
Point2D.Float p1R = new Point2D.Float(0,0);
Point2D.Float p2R = new Point2D.Float(0,0);
Point2D.Float p3R = new Point2D.Float(0,0);
float dx = Math.cos(rot);
float dy = Math.sin(rot);
p1R.x = p1.x * dx + p1.y * -dy + x;
p1R.y = p1.x * dy + p1.y *  dx + y;
p2R.x = p2.x * dx + p2.y * -dy + x;
p2R.y = p2.x * dy + p2.y *  dx + y;
p3R.x = p3.x * dx + p3.y * -dy + x;
p3R.y = p3.x * dy + p3.y *  dx + y;
```

Comment: I copy and pasted this code into my code and the ship still does not rotate.

Comment: @Reddish No it would not, it is just an example of how to rotate a point you need to adapt it to your code.